# Reduction formula question (A Level- further Maths)

Tags: integration

Find an expression for $$I_n= \int_0^\pi x^n (\cos x)\,dx$$ in terms of $I_{n-2}$.

Comment: Did you try integration by part?

Comment: Yeah. I got to $$I_n= -n*\int_0^\pi x^{n-1} (\sin x)\,dx$$

Comment: Good. Try to do integration by part again....

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: I have to differentiate x^{n-1} right?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I will in future. Thanks

Comment: Yes. (When you do once, $\sin$ shows up. If you do it again, you get $\cos$).

Comment: Ok so my answer is,       $$I_n=-n\pi^{n-1}-n (n-1)I_{n-2}$$

Comment: If you've found the answer after you asked a question, you can post it and mark it as accepted. =)